# SQL search brands in encoded url

Tags: mysql, sql, urlencode

(EDIT: to anyone trying this, just try find another way, you'll only loose time, some website use their own fabricant ID... In my case I'm gonna try do it by editing the **scraper** used to get the url before encoding)

I'm currently making a SQL query to find products related to a brands in a list of affiliated url
Currently I'm still looking for missing case, so if someone have already made this kind of query, I'm open to any tips or hints :)

Here's how's generated my current query using php

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_boutique_products.' ';

for($i = 0 ; $i < 2; $i++){
  if($i == 0){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
  }else{
    $sql .= " OR ";
  }

  $value_dash = str_replace(" ", "-",$value);
  $value_underscore = str_replace(" ", "",$value);
  $value_plus = str_replace(" ", "+", $value);

  $sql .= 'url LIKE "%.'.$value.'.%" 
    OR url LIKE "%.'.$value_dash.'.%"
    OR url LIKE "%.'.$value_underscore.'.%"
    OR url LIKE "http://'.$value_dash.'.%" 
    OR url LIKE "http://'.$value_underscore.'.%" 
    OR url LIKE "https://'.$value_dash.'.%" 
    OR url LIKE "https://'.$value_underscore.'.%" 
    OR url LIKE "%'.urlencode(str_replace("+", "%20", urlencode($value))).'%" 

    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.$value.'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.htmlentities($value).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.urlencode(urlencode($value)).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.urlencode(str_replace("+", "%20", urlencode($value))).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.$value_dash.'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.str_replace(" ", "\%2520", $value).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.$value_plus.'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $value).'\%2F%" 
    
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.$value.'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.htmlentities($value).'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.urlencode(urlencode($value)).'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.urlencode(str_replace("+", "%20", urlencode($value))).'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.$value_dash.'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.str_replace(" ", "\%2520", $value).'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.$value_plus.'-%" 
    OR url LIKE "%\%2F'.preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $value).'-%" 
    
    OR url LIKE "%-'.$value.'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.htmlentities($value).'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.urlencode(urlencode($value)).'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.urlencode(str_replace("+", "%20", urlencode($value))).'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.$value_dash.'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.str_replace(" ", "\%2520", $value).'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.$value_plus.'?%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $value).'?%" 
    
    OR url LIKE "%-'.$value.'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.htmlentities($value).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.urlencode(urlencode($value)).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.urlencode(str_replace("+", "%20", urlencode($value))).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.$value_dash.'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.str_replace(" ", "\%2520", $value).'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.$value_plus.'\%2F%" 
    OR url LIKE "%-'.preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $value).'\%2F%" 
    ';
  $value = no_accent_char($value);
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean “scraper”  - i.e. getting data by reading it from HTML web pages - rather than “scrapper” - i.e. someone who throws things away.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using